# ANSI C (ISO C90): Can scanf read/accept an unsigned char?

Tags: c, gcc, scanf, c89

Simple question: Can scanf read/accept a "small integer" into an unsigned char in ANSI C?

example code un_char.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char character;

    scanf("%hhu", &character);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compiled as:

```
$ gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -o un_char un_char.c
un_char.c: In function ‘main’:
un_char.c:8: warning: ISO C90 does not support the ‘hh’ gnu_scanf length modifier
```

`hh` isn't supported by ISO C90.  So what scanf conversion can be used in this situation?

Comment: Change `-ansi` to `-std=c99` if you don't need your code to work on Windows.

Answer (score 12):

No: C89 (C90) does not support `'%hhu'` to read a string of digits into an unsigned char.  That is a feature in C99.

You would have to read into an unsigned integer (`'%u'`) or unsigned short (`'%hu'`) and then check that the result is with the range of an unsigned char.

Answer (score 3):

Read it into an unsigned short/int and do some range checking after if you need to.

Comment: Unsigned short would be the better datatype as that's 16 bits...just knock off the upper 8 bits.. :)

Comment: @tommieb75: There's no guarantee that `unsigned short` is 16 bits.  There's no guarantee that `unsigned char` is 8 bits either.

Comment: @jamesdlin: I agree...due to the different processors/compilers/linkers/runtime environments... :O :)

Comment: @jamesdlin: I believe there is a guarantee that a char is at least 8 bits, which is enough

Comment: @Matt Joiner: Yes, but my point was that you can't just knock off the upper 8 bits (as tommieb76 suggested) and that you should do range-checking (as nos suggested).