# Format specifier of _int8 data type in C

Tags: c, integer, overflow

What is the format specifier for an _int8 data type?

I am using "%hd" but it is giving me an error about stack corruption. Thanks :)

This is a snippet of the code:

```
signed _int8 answer;

printf("----Technology Quiz----\n\n");
printf("The IPad came out in which year?\n");
printf("Year: ");
scanf("%hd", &answer);
printf("\n\n");
printf("The answer you provided was: %hd\n\n", answer);
```

Comment: %d should works. did you test it ?

Comment: How do you fit a year in an 8-bit type?

Comment: That's the purpose of the program.  I want to show how using the wrong data type can crash a program or lead to unexpected results.

Comment: Using %d does not work with scanf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the "explicit width" typedefs like `int8_t` and `uint_fast16_t` portably in C99 in the format strings of `printf` and `scanf`, you need to `#include <inttypes.h>` and then use the string macros `PRIi8` and `PRIuFAST16`, like so:

```
#include <stdint.h>   // for the typedefs (redundant, actually)
#include <inttypes.h> // for the macros

int8_t a = 1;
uint_fast16_t b = 2;

printf("A = %" PRIi8 ", B = %" PRIuFAST16 "\n", a, b);
```

See [the manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/inttypes.h.html) for a full list, and cross-reference it with the typedefs in [`<stdint.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/basedefs/stdint.h.html).

Answer (score 5):

man scanf: `%hhd` "... but the next pointer is a pointer to a signed char or unsigned char". An `_int8` is equivalent to a `signed char` in any system you're going to be doing `scanf` on.

```
signed _int8 answer;
scanf("%hhd", &answer);
printf("You entered %d\n\n", answer);
```

Comment: Use `%hhd` in scanf and `%d` in printf, i just verified that it works.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` with `%hd` reads a `short int`, which might be 16 bit on a 32 bit machine. So you are reading into answer and one byte beyond, thus the stack corruption.

Up to C90 there is no type specifier to read an 8 bit int with scanf.

`%hhd` is only available since C99, see also [ANSI C (ISO C90): Can scanf read/accept an unsigned char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231056/ansi-c-iso-c90-can-scanf-read-accept-an-unsigned-char).

Comment: @Matthew: What platform/compiler (+version) are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

%hd will allow  you to get a "short int", which is typically 16 bits, not 8 bits as might imagine.   If %hhd is not supported,  you may not have a good way to do this, other than scanning in as a short and assigning.